# SOLR Indexing via DB SP

Tags: solr

I have 12 cores that hold about 500 thousand records each and I index the data from TSQL via an SP since the data has multiple joins from various tables and other factors involved.

When I fun a full import it takes me 20 min to index 500k records and sometimes even longer, is there a way I can speed things up?

Also Delta imports are not as instant as I would like them to be is there a way around this? for example: I update a record via my page and click save it takes around 5-6 seconds for the delta to index and then show me the change and i have to refresh the page to see the changes.